# Avoid selecting duplicate MySQL rows

Tags: mysql

I am selecting rows with

```
SELECT `playerid` FROM `lb-world` WHERE replaced=50 AND type=0 >= 0.01
```

But in my table I have

```
playerid | replaced | type | date
12       | 50       | 0    | 2010
12       | 50       | 0    | 2011
12       | 50       | 0    | 2012
```

How to select it just once?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT playerid....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want `playerid`, you can use `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT `playerid` FROM `lb-world` WHERE replaced=50 AND type=0 >= 0.01
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT `playerid` FROM `lb-world` 
WHERE replaced=50 AND type=0
GROUP BY playerid, replaced, type
```

This should be generic.
Anyway, if you're sure you just want playerid, use this

```
SELECT DISTINCT playerid FROM lb-world
WHERE replaced=50 AND type=0
```

Comment: Why GROUP BY? There's only `playerid` in the select list

Comment: @Michael: yes, you're right... but if he wants to add some field it's still working... anyway, ok I will change my answer

Comment: I think using `GROUP BY` is perfectly valid as well. As stated in MySQL documentation, in term of optimization, both functions are very close. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT playerid..
```

as @Michael said